# How to load tabs in url using hash

Tags: jquery

Hi there fellow people of stackoverflow!
I have a question how to load a tab called #A and one called #B by using http://mydomaine.com/index.html#A or #B.

It's just basic bootstrap code. I really don't know anything about jQuery so I need some help.

```html
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">Gutter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">Jenter</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: What code are you using to open the modal? Can we see what you've coded so far?

Comment: hey @Someuserbms - welcome to stackoverflow! You can [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33373449/edit) your question and add the code - have done it for you above. It is not good practice to add code in comments that really should be part of the question

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this when the page loads:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  switch(window.location.hash) {
    case '#A':
      //DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO IF A
      break;
    case '#B':
      //DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO IF B
      break;
    default:
      //DEFAULT ACTION
  } 
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer.
But my I really have no clue about jQuery and tried to google it all day.
I tried to do this to see if localhost/index.html#A worked but it doesn't. Any ideas?

`$( document ).ready(function() { switch(window.location.hash) {
    case '#A':
      alert('A');
      break;
    case '#B':
     alert('B');
      break;
    default:
      //DEFAULT ACTION
  } 
});`

Comment: Are you able to show any more of your code @Someuserbms? Have you included jQuery?

Comment: Yes, jQuery is included. What I want to do is to toggle a nav-tab from bootstrap just using http://url.com/#B

Comment: @Someuserbms can you show the code you have tried so far please?